# Where is the sql script in activator slick template?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

When I first run this play-slick template with `activator run`, the web page shows a sql script need to be run first.

```
Database 'default' needs evolution![An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
```

Where is the sql script located at? I tried searching through the project and couldn't find it.

```
https://github.com/loicdescotte/activator-play-slick#master
```

Comment: The script should be located within `conf/evolutions/default`, however, I can't see it there. When you run the solution, does it not prompt you to run the script or mark is resolved?

Comment: Script will be generated from the model in conf/evolutions/default when you run application and hit the browser (http://localhost:9000).

Comment: @grzesiekw Does it automatically generates the sql script base on the `case class Cat(name: String, color: String)` or is it base on other stuff? And if its automatically generated how would you customize it? Like adding constraints, indexes etc.

Comment: @Kevin Script is generated from Table class - in this example CatsTable. You can customize script by adding more stuff to this class, for example: `def idx = index("idx_name", name, unique = true)` creates sql for unique index: `create unique index "idx_name" on "CAT" ("name");`. Please check http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/schemas.html for details. Also you should be aware that  this project uses old (2.1.0) slick version.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, if I change to `play-slick` version to `1.1.1` I run into import problem for `import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._` , `import scala.slick.profile.RelationalTableComponent.Table` and `import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._` , is there a change log somewhere that I can reference to?

Comment: @Kevin There is a migration guide from Play Slick 0.8 to 1.1 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickMigrationGuide